# How to display `pdfsearch` output in Shiny in table format with visible columns of text , page number , line number?

Tags: r, shiny

I created a simple `pdfsearch` search option with Shiny . However I want the output to be in the form of table for easy readability. I tried using Data Table package , but do not seem to get the right format I need .

```
library(pdfsearch)
library(shiny)
library(DT)


file <- system.file('pdf', 'rhyme.pdf', package = 'pdfsearch')

word_sentence <-function(word) {keyword_search(file,    
                                               keyword = word,
                                               path = TRUE)}



retobj <- function(word) {
  x <- word_sentence(word)
  page <- x$page_num
  line <- x$line_num
  text <- x$line_text
  return(paste0(text," "," *Page no-",page," *line-",line))
}


ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(dashboardBody(
  img(src='image.jpg', align = "left"),style = "padding-top:20px",
  

  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2,
           h5(HTML("<strong>Enter a word.Click \"SEARCH\" </strong>")),
           wellPanel(
             textInput("inputString","Enter a word here",value=" "),
             submitButton("SEARCH"),
             
           )),
    
    column(width= 7,style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
           h4("Search Results"), 
           wellPanel(            
             tags$style("#mytext { white-space: pre-line; }"),
             textOutput("mytext")
           ))
         )
       )
     ) 
    ) 


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytext <- renderPrint({
    sentences <- retobj(input$inputString)
    length(sentences)
    cat(paste0(1:length(sentences)," - ",sentences,sep= '\n'))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I am now getting the output when i search the word 'hill' for eg. as :

```
1.jack went to the hill blah blah *Page no- 12 * line no -34
2.jack went rolling on hill blah  *Page no 17 *line no - 56
3.jill climbed the hill blah blah * Page no 34  * line no -89
''''
20......
```

I would like the output to be in table format displayed in Shiny such as :

```
              Text                          Page no       Line No 

  jack went to the hill blah                   12            34

  jack went rolling on hill blah               17            56
 
  jill climbed the hill   blah                 34            89
 
  '    ''''''''''
```

using `renderDataTable`in `server` part and `tableOutput` in `ui` of Shiny gives me output in R console instead of Shiny and I tried
`retob <- function({.....tableHTML(text,page,line)}` but it was giving me error as says not matrix format.Is there a cleaner way to just format the content in the above mentioned way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `retobj` function actually was the problem, because it creates only one string as the return value. However, `keyword_search` already returns a tibble, so you can directly use this output and `dplyr` to bring it in the desired format and finally `DT` to display it:

```
library(pdfsearch)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)


file <- system.file('pdf', '1501.00450.pdf', package = 'pdfsearch')

word_sentence <-function(word) {keyword_search(file,    
                                               keyword = word,
                                               path = TRUE)}



ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(dashboardBody(
  
  
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2,
           h5(HTML("<strong>Enter a word.Click \"SEARCH\" </strong>")),
           wellPanel(
             textInput("inputString","Enter a word here",value=" "),
             submitButton("SEARCH"),
             
           )),
    
    column(width= 7,style = "max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;",
           h4("Search Results"), 
           wellPanel(            
             tags$style("#mytext { white-space: pre-line; }"),
             DTOutput("mytext")
           ))
  )
)
) 
) 


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$mytext <- renderDT({
    results <- word_sentence(input$inputString)
    results <- results %>% 
      select(line_text, page_num, line_num) %>% 
      rename(Text = line_text,
             `Page no` = page_num,
             `Line no` = line_num)
    datatable(results)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: beautiful ! thank you . I can even dispense the  left search bar too with this. Yes I was confused how to use the `keyword_search` tibble within shiny and exclude few columns